# I need help thinking of a different approach of implementing a C++ style Linked List in C

Tags: c++, c, list, pointers, linked-list

This is for an assignment in my C class; I already have experience with C++. The issue I am having is that my implementation simply seems shady as hell. My current implementation only allows for one LinkedList to be used at a time. I know I can always just pass on a pointer to the structure, but I wanted to avoid that. Hence, it became really shady. I also have no way to regulate the scope of the functions; they are visible globally. Also notice that pointer to the structure in the h file; that is the reason why I can't have more than one in one program. Other than passing in the pointer to every function, can anyone think of another way?

It's only currently singly linked, but the Doubly Linked one won't take more than 30 minutes.

[LinkedList.h](http://pastebin.com/J479P2Db)

[LinkedList.c](http://pastebin.com/xtpnTn2C)

Comment: You just have to pass the pointer to the linked list as an argument. That's ultimately what's going on with the *this* pointer in C++ (it's passed implicitly).

Comment: What is a C++ style linked list as opposed to a C one?

Comment: You said _I know I can always just pass on a pointer to the structure, but I wanted to avoid that._ Why do you want to avoid that? What problems would this cause that you want to avoid?

Comment: In your .h file I see a struct for the Linked List but I do not see a struct that should represent the Linked List Items... Seems like you're missing a big piece of the puzzle.

Comment: @qdii, I would assume its one that won't use C++ exclusive stuff like the STL.

Comment: @David - I think you have just discovered why C++ was invented. In C you have to (and *want to*) handle all the tiny details yourself. That's the philosophy of the language - nothing is hidden.

Comment: To hazard a guess: one point of this exercise is realising that both your issues (parameter passing and namespace pollution) are unavoidable in C. Another point is that it gives some insight into what's going on "backstage" in C++.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in C you will pass a pointer to a struct to every function that operates on it.

```
typedef struct list list_t;

list_t *list_new();
void list_delete(list_t *list);
void list_insert_back(list_t *list, void *obj);
void list_insert_front(list_t *list, void *obj);
/* etc. */
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "regulate the scope".  If you are talking about function names, then you typically prefix the function names with a common prefix like `list_` above.

Behind the scenes, this ends up working the same as C++ code.  The C++ compiler prefixes member functions (like the example uses `list_`, although the C++ compiler does it differently), and the C++ compiler also passes the `this` parameter implicitly.

In fact, the very oldest C++ compiler (cfront) would translate C++ code directly into C code like the above.

Note that in contrast to the typical C++ method, you don't have to define the linked list structure in your header file -- this allows you to change the data structure without breaking ABI compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

Since the rest of your question has been answered, I want to add that you can limit the scope of functions: simply declare them `static`, this will give them internal linkage:

```
/* This function won't be seen outside of the header file */
static void foo(list *l);
```

This is basically equivalent to declaring a private function `foo` in a class:

```
class list
{
private:
    void foo();    
};
```